# Confusion about joint and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes

A person has 16 headaches (H) in 30 days, means P(H) = 16/30 = 0.53

The person tracked his Stress Level and Lack of Sleep for those 30 days. It is assumed that High Stress (HS) and Lack of Sleep (LoS) are independent events and might be responsible for his headaches. Based on the tracked data and using a contingency table,

P(H|HS) = 0.88 and P(H|LoS) = 0.75.

Now the person wants to calculate combined effect of High Stress and Lack of Sleep on his headaches.

Assuming HS⊥LoS we have,

\begin{align}
P(H|HS,LoS)&=\frac{P(HS,LoS,H)}{P(HS,LoS)}=\frac{P(HS,LoS|H)P(H)}{P(HS,LoS)}\\
&=\frac{P(HS|H)P(LoS|H)P(H)}{P(HS)P(LoS)}=\frac{P(H|LoS)P(H|HS)}{P(H)}
\end{align}

So, by calculation **P(H|HS,LoS) = 1.24**

How is this possible (probability is greater than 1)? What am I doing wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Generally, you cannot assume that just because two events, $A$ and $B$ are independent that they are *conditionally* independent. $A\perp B$ does not imply $A|C \perp B|C$ for some event $C$. That's where you're going off the rails.

Comment: @Bey then how to approach this overall problem?

Comment: Even if you do assume that HS and LoS are conditionally independent given H, you should expand the denominator fully from step 2 of the right hand side. That should make it clearer that things don't subsequently factor the way you were thinking.